# Add a PayPal Checkout Button to Onepage Checkout page?

Tags: onepage-checkout, paypal-express, ce-1.9.2.4

Searched around, but found no true answer. I wish to add a PayPal Express Button, similar to the Cart page, under the "Your Checkout Progress" review steps.
Is this possible please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by overriding the base phtml file.

this is located at:
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml

copy this to:
app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml

and add the code for the Paypal Express Button - template for this is at:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/shortcut.phtml

which demonstrates the html and various calls to implement.
I dont have a specific coded suggestion but this should give you the right pointers.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check on that. Is there a 'short-code' for the PayPal button?

Comment: `<ul class="checkout-types">
        <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?>
            <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
            <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>`

Comment: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: have amended my answer with the base location of the Paypal Express button which is the standard implementation - this should give enough I guess to customise/copy for your needs :)